# mysql check userID of last x posts

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php chat script on my site that I made, and I want to add in an anti-spam measure so that it wont post your message if the last 5 messages in the mysql table are by you.

Do I have to cycle through the last 5 with a recordset or is there a SQL statement that can just check this for me?

the table fields are just 'date' 'text' 'userid'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query like this to get how many of the last 5 messages where by the person in question.

```
select 
     sum(if(userid = '$user_id',1,0)) = 5 
     from (
         select userid from chat order by id desc limit 5
     );
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: is date a date field or a timestamp?

Comment: i didnt use date, i used ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: This should return something because it's true: select sum(if(user_id = 13652, 1,0))=2 from chat order by date desc limit 2

Comment: drop the =2 just to see what's coming through

Comment: When I drop that it returns the total sum of rows (167) instead of just 2

Comment: Combination of my solution and @NateFromKalamazoo 's

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:

```
select userid, count(date) as howmany from 
( 
  select userid, date 
  from YOURTABLENAME 
  order by date desc
  limit 5
) 
  lastfiverows
group by userid
order by howmany
```

Then in PHP check to see if the "howmany" field is five, and the userid matches the user in question.

Answer (score 0):

Order the record set (ORDER BY) by date (DESC) and LIMIT it to 5